# .htaccess rewrite outputs undesired content. I think?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a URL using .htaccess. I am running on Apache version 2.2.15.

Contents of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule cars/(.*) cars/member_page.php?user=$1
RewriteRule cars/(.*)/ cars/member_page.php?user=$1
```

Contents of member_page.php:

```
<?php
echo $_GET[user];
?>
```

URL entered into browser:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/cars/user1
```

The browser outputs the string "member_page.php" instead of "user1"

How do I make it output the contents of (.*) from the original URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this format:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule cars/(.*) cars/member_page.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule cars/(.*)/ cars/member_page.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Turns out that I was rewriting cars/whatever to cars/member_page.php. This creates the problem of rewriting to the same directory that the rewrite is on.

So

```
cars/user1
```

was rewritten to

```
cars/member_page.php/user=member_page.php
```

It was rewritten twice using the content from the second rewrite as the final information. The solution is to move member_page.php to a different directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule cars/(.*) memberscars/member_page.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule cars/(.*)/ memberscars/member_page.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, its `$_GET['user']`, not `$_GET[user]` (note the quotes). Regarding your mod_rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule cars/(.*) cars/member_page.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule cars/(.*)/ cars/member_page.php?user=$1 [L]
```

L means last rule to be applied.

Comment: But a 302 redirect is probably not what he wants, is it? Won't the [L] already do?